# Displaying XML in HTML - how to preserve line breaks?

Tags: php, html, xml, formatting

I'm working on a function that takes the content from Microsoft Word `.docx` files and displays them in a `web page`. The text renders fine, but I can't seem to get it to display line breaks?

The code for my function is below:

```
function readDocx($filePath) {
$zip = new ZipArchive;
//Create new ZIP archive
$dataFile = "word/document.xml";

//Open received archive file
if (true === $zip->open($filePath)) {
    //if open successful, search for the data file inside the archive
    if (($index = $zip ->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
        //if found, read it to the string
        $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);

        //load XML from a string. skips errors and warnings
        $xml = new DOMDocument();
        $xml->loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

        $xmldata = $xml->saveXML();
        $xmldata = str_replace("</w:p>", "^^^^^^" . "&#10" . "<br>" . "\n" . "<br />" . "<p>" . "%%%", $xmldata);

        echo strip_tags($xmldata);

    }
    $zip->close();
}   
//in case of failure, return an empty string
else {
    echo "An error has occurred while opening the file - please try again!";
}
}
```

---

The output of the function is something like:

**Original -**

"Lorem ipsum

lorem ipsum"

**Output -**

"Lorem ipsum ^^^^^ %%% lorem ipsum"

---

I've looked up other answers on `SO` but couldn't find anything that worked for solving the issue... Any help would be greatly appreciated! (Although you might have to explain in more basic terms, I'm still a rookie :D)

Comment: not sure, but try to set preserveWhiteSpace property

Comment: nope, didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone in the future: `strip_tags()` removes HTML tags as well as PHP ones, so when I used strip_tags() it was removing all the `<br>`'s and the like as well...

Solved the problem by inserting a dummy string in place of the line breaks before using `strip_tags()`, then using `str_replace()` to re-insert them (this time as `<br>`) afterwards. Lesson learned: read the documentation first! ><